# Badrequest in JSON SCHEMA with 'oneOf'

Tags: json, express, jsonschema

I am using the package [express-jsonschema](https://github.com/trainiac/express-jsonschema) to validate the body of the request.

My schema is:

```
{
    type: 'object',
    oneOf: [
    { $ref: "#/definitions/one" },
    { $ref: "#/definitions/two" },
    { $ref: "#/definitions/three" }
   ],
   definitions: { 
    one: {
     type: 'string'
    },
    two: {
     type: 'string'
    }
    three: {
     type: 'string'
    }

}
```

The body of my request is:

```
{
"one": "asdf"

}
```

The result of my request is a **BadRequest**, I have read this example [Example JSON SCHEMA](http://json-schema.org/example2.html), but my code doesnt work.
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is an object with a property, not a string. So each of the definitions (or at least the definition of "one"'s) type should be an object with a property, not a string.

This is a valid schema for your request and might be what you are trying to do (don't have enough info to be sure):

```
{
    type: 'object',
    oneOf: [
    { $ref: "#/definitions/one" },
    { $ref: "#/definitions/two" },
    { $ref: "#/definitions/three" }
   ],
   definitions: { 
    one: {
     type: 'object',
     properties: {
         one: { 
           required: true,
           type: "string"
         }
       }
    },
    two: {
     type: 'object',
     properties: {
         two: { 
           required: true,
           type: "string"
         }
       }
    },
    three: {
     type: 'object',
     properties: {
         three: { 
           required: true,
           type: "string"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have provide your code , but now , I have received a error: `Data is valid against more than one schema from \"oneOf\": indices 0 and 1`. I would like that body to be : `{ one : 'string'} or { two: 'string} or { three :' string' }`. Only it s allowed one of this three keywords

Comment: I used this validator to check http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and it validates fine for those three ( one: 'string', two: 'string' and three: 'string') and not for any other keyword